# Add HABTM data in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

In my app,  `Users` HABTM `Solicitations`.

After saving the form using `$this->Solicitation->save($this->request->data)`, I need to add another `user_id` value in the solicitations_users table.

```
$data[] = array('User' => array('id' => 5), 'Solicitation' => array('id' => 77));
$data[] = array('User' => array('id' => 6), 'Solicitation' => array('id' => 77));

  $this->Solicitation->saveMany($data);
```

My `$data`is this:

```
array(
'User' => array(
    'id' => (int) 6
),
'Solicitation' => array(
    'id' => '54'
)
)
```

I need to save the association in the form and then add the new record above to the `solicitations_users` table as well. It's only saving the `6` and not the data from the form. It just saves the form if I delete the second `save`.

I realized that in the DB, this is jumping one `id`. 
This should be `'id' 36 => 5; 'id' 37 => 6`. It looks like that is updating the table.

Here is the query:

[image]

Comment: If you could add your model Solicitation than it would be very helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys.

But, based on this answer : [CakePHP: Creating new HABTM row instead updates other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16220313/cakephp-creating-new-habtm-row-instead-updates-other)

I found that instead of `SaveAll` create a new row, It update that already exists with new records.
Because of this, i'v used `query()` to add a new row.

```
$this->Solicitation->query("INSERT INTO `contratos`.`solicitation_users` (user_id,solicitation_id) values($id, $solicitation");
```

Thanks for all

Comment: this is just a workaround because it doesn't use cake syntax imho.

Comment: If you see the question i'v cited, there's no way to do this using the `save` methods on Cake

Comment: did you try `'unique' =>'keepExisting'` in your association array?

Answer (score 1):

What is your posted data structure like?

According to [the cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm) it should be

```
Array(
    'User' => Array(
        'id' => 6
    ),
    'Solicitation' => Array(
        'title' => 'A request'
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi!! i posted my `$data` array

Comment: Does the user and the solicitation exist before adding the association? You should also check out saveAll() and the other methods together with their requirements.

Comment: Hi!! I found the answer, pls check.

Answer (score 1):

When you save an habtm relationship cake delete all the records relative to thet item and rewrite just the ones you are saving.

see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#what-to-do-when-habtm-becomes-complicated) about it

So you have to save all your records at the same time providing an array like:

try

```
$data = array(
    'Solicitation' => array('id' => 77),
    'User' => array(
        'User' => array(6, 7)
    )
);

$this->Solicitation->saveAll($data);
```

you can also set `'unique' =>'keepExisting'` in your habtm association array

Comment: This could do with an explanation as to why this fixes the posted problem.

Comment: Hi!! I found the answer, pls check.

Answer (score 1):

Give one of these two a shot:

```
$data[] = array('User' => array('id' => 5), 'Solicitation' => array('id' => 77));
$data[] = array('User' => array('id' => 6), 'Solicitation' => array('id' => 77));

$this->Solicitation->saveMany($data, array('deep' => true));
```

OR

```
$data[] = array('SolicitationsUser' => array('User.id' => 5,'Solicitation.id' => 77));
$data[] = array('SolicitationsUser' => array('User.id' => 6,'Solicitation.id' => 77));

$this->Solicitation->saveMany($data);
```

Comment: Hi!! I found the answer, pls check.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use foreach. Like-

```
$data[] = array('User' => array('id' => 5), 'Solicitation' => array('id' => 77));
$data[] = array('User' => array('id' => 6), 'Solicitation' => array('id' => 77));

foreach($data as $da){
  $this->Solicitation->saveMany($da);
}
```

Comment: Hi!! I found the answer, pls check.